# How do I make my text keep the variable number and not the reference in javascript D3?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I have a tooltip that runs everytime I mouseover a svg element.

I've added the code in a loop that goes through i iterations:

```
.on("mouseover", function(d){return tooltip.style("visibility", "visible")
                .text(d["GEO/ACL00"] + " " + d[headers[i]]);})
```

But it doesn't keep the value of i, it only references i. Once the mouse hovers over, the loop is already over and i is the last value of the loop.

How do I make it look for d[headers[24]] for example instead of d[headers[i]]?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use the index, you have to set the second parameter (traditionally called `i`, for *index*) in the anonymous function:

```
selection.on("mouseover", function(d, i){
    //second parameter ---------------^
    //code here
})
```

Here is a demo, hover over the circles:

```js
var svg = d3.select("svg");

var circles = svg.selectAll("foo")
  .data(d3.range(10))
  .enter()
  .append("circle")
  .attr("cy", 30)
  .attr("cx", function(d){ return 30 + 25 * d})
  .attr("fill", "teal")
  .attr("r", 10);
  
circles.on("mouseover", function(d,i){
  console.log("This is circle index " + i)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.js"></script>
<svg></svg>
```

Comment: This was from a while ago and the problem was solved using a different method, but say the "i" I want to use is from a loop already running, how would I do that?

Comment: If you have a different problem, please ask another question. Also, as you are new at S.O., please accept a working answer (the green tick at the top left of the answer), it gives you points and shows another users that the answer worked... or maybe not, since you said that used a different method.